# Magento caching (APC, memcached)

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I'm trying to understand how caching actually works and which caching system should I use, but the more I read the more confused I am.

Using default cache in my magento store (1.9.2) doesn't realy work. After a few weeks my cache folders are more than 10gb and becouse of that website started to work very slow. I have to clear cache folders every few days or so to make it work reasonably.

My hosting provider allows me to change caching to APC or XCache. I can also buy memcached (64mb), but I'm not sure if it will work becouse its size?

Could someone explain to me what those cache systems actually do, and which one of them should I use to make my magento work fast? Or maybe combining two of them is a way to go?

EDIT: How often should I clean cache catalogs via cronjob? What's the point of using second-level cache ( /var/cache/ folder ) if I'm going to clear it quite often to prevent slow working (what's the point of caching at all if it makes my website slow)

Answer (score 0):

you must setup a cronjob for that but 10 Gb it's not normal.
Are you talking about this folder /html/var/cache ? or the cache image 
/html/media/catalog/product/cache ? in the both case its not normal.

For CronJob 
You need setup Admin => system => configuration => system => ‘Cron (Scheduled Tasks)’ tab.
And also config both file in magento cron.sh cron.php depending your system
Flush the cache in my memory is not include so you have to add it in the cron.php
Have a look in first step [Configure and run cron](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)
And enjoy

Comment: Ps : APC works well with Magento also for  a better understanding of magento cache maybe watch there [link] https://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/the-right-magento-cache-strategy-for-best-performance/[link]

Comment: After 1 day: /var/cache size is ~200mb. /media/catalog/product/cache is ~1gb. I understand that ain't normal, but what is causing it? About fast-cache I did a research, as far as I know I do not have to set APC etc. if I am using PHP7 becouse it has its own caching system , am I right?

Comment: /media/catalog/product/cache continue growing ? this cache are the different image resize when all are batch resize he doesnt normally continue growing ? what is the weight of the biggest image in this folder ?